# Create URL in Yii with element name with #

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I need to create URLs in Yii with specifying a div on the page to focus when clicked... I know I need to put the div name with `#` in the URL, but how do I specify that in createUrl function of Yii...

The `createUrl()` function only provides options for parameters, not for elements...as per my knowledge.

Comment: FYI, i think this is an awesome question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check [createUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail):

> additional GET parameters (name=>value). Both the name and value will be URL-encoded. If the name is '#', the corresponding value will be treated as an anchor and will be appended at the end of the URL.

You can add it like this:

```
 echo $this->createUrl('controller/action',array('#'=>'name'));
```