# Yii - link to a section of static page

Tags: yii

I am able to link to a static page like

```
CHtml::link('About Us',array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about'));
```

but how to link to a specific part of the static page, so that it renders 
something like this

```
href="static_page.html#section"
```

I tried this and it doesn't work.

```
CHtml::link('Section',array('/site/page', 'view'=>'static_page#section'))
```

Comment: Have you tried `CHtml::link('Section',array('/site/page', 'view'=>'static_page', '#' => 'section'))`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085025/create-url-in-yii-with-element-name-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way would be `CHtml::link('Section',array('/site/page', 'view'=>'static_page', '#'=>'section'))`